# jruby dragonfly gem - "incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT" when open file with special characters

Tags: encoding, jruby, special-characters, filenames, dragonfly-gem

I'm a newbie in jruby, I'm currently working on a Jruby app that use Dragonfly gem to handle image upload.

The problem here is when uploading a zip file (called abc.zip) containing a file name like this "nür ümläütö.PNG", the .png file is first stored in /tmp directory. The gem instead of looking for the path "/tmp/nür ümläütö.PNG.4483.14119", it looks for path "/tmp/n\u00C3\u0083\u00C2\u00BCr \u00C3\u0083\u00C2\u00BCml\u00C3\u0083\u00C2\u00A4\u00C3\u0083\u00C2\u00BCt\u00C3\u0083\u00C2\u00B6.PNG.4483.14119" which doesn't exist. And this doesn't happen if I use native ruby. I have done lots of googling on the last 2 days but no progress

I seriously don't know what and why the problem happens, please shed some lights for me!